# Find a portion of a string, and add an attribute to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a string of html `<option>` elements contained in the variable `options`. What I'm trying to do is find the `<option>` within that string with the attribute, `value="YE"` and add the attribute `selected="selected"` to it.

I thought the following might work, but it doesn't, it simply stops the rest of the script from executing properly:

```
var options = '<?php echo str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $geo_options); ?>';
options.find('option[value=YE]').attr('selected','selected');
```

If `options.find('option[value=YE]').attr('selected','selected');` is commented out, the rest of the script works fine.

I've also tried to prepend it with `var options = option.find(..`, which didn't work.

**So, the question is**, how can I in jQuery/JavaScript find an `<option>` element with a particular value in a string of `<option>` elements, and add the attribute/value of `selected="selected"` to it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not making `<option>` elements, so you can't add attributes to them. You'll first need a `<select>` element and fill that with `<option>`s. I'm assuming that works.

> ... the rest of the script works fine.

And then:

```
select.find('option[value=YE]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Is that what you mean?

**edit**
What's in the options var exactly? A string like `"<option value=1>bla</option><option value=2>oele</option><option value=3>bar</option>"`?

Comment: Edit: Yes, that's exactly what's in there. But I like your idea of doing it after it's placed in `<select>` tags, as oppose to being in a variable, unless it's not a lot harder to do the same thing while it's in the string.

Comment: I know what you mean and that was the gist of my answer. Fill the `<select>` and then set `selected`. How do you fill the `<select>`? I'm pretty sure IE won't take `select.innerHTML = '..options..'`...

Comment: It's a lot harder to do it while it's still in a string =)

Comment: `$('select[name="' + data.name +"']).html();`, the select name is dynamic and comes in via AJAX. If this isn't cross-browser compatible, it's not really important, as this is an app for webmasters, where for the 5-10% of them (if that number) that use non-standards compliant browsers, a message is displayed telling them that they need an updated standards compliant browser :).